# De Bruijn indices in Isabelle and Coq

Tags: coq, isabelle

I would like to be able use something like [de Bruijn indices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_index) in Isabelle or in Coq, in order to refer to variables that have been introduced by quantifiers. For example, instead of writing:

```
forall x. forall y. (p x y)
```

I would like to write something like:

```
forall x. forall y. (p '2' '1')
```

where the indices '2' and '1' indicate that these variables are bound by, respectively, the second and the first quantifier (counting from inside to outside).

The reason why I need to do this is that the quantifiers will actually be hidden by abbreviations, and therefore I will not know the names of the variables. My formula will look like this:

```
box box (p '2' '1')
```

where box should be an abbreviation for something that introduces an unnamed/hidden bound variable, and I want '2' and '1' to refer to the unnamed/hidden variables introduced by the leftmost and rightmost "box", respectively.

Is it possible to achieve something like this in Isabelle or in Coq??

Comment: This reminds me of the locally nameless work by Arthur Chargeraud in Coq, maybe you can find some ideas there.

Comment: Thanks, @Vinz! I read this paper of his: http://www.chargueraud.org/research/2009/ln/main.pdf. The locally nameless representation is indeed what I want. However, I do not want to do a deep embedding and define my own language as a datatype in Coq or in Isabelle. Instead I would like to be able to use the "locally nameless" notation style when writing formulas directly/shallowly in the language of Isabelle/Coq. His paper suggests that Coq and Isabelle (or at least early versions of these systems) already use a locally nameless representation internally. But is this available to the user?

Comment: No it's not. Maybe you can emulate such a system with notations, but I don't think you'll be able to go very far. These systems have been build to avoid having to deal with deBruijn indexes or other binding tricks

Comment: Is the syntax highlighting as expected or is it weird/unexpected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only speak constructively for Isabelle here: the formal syntax uses standard de-Bruijn representation of lambda terms internally, and there are various ways to reuse that for your own syntax and special notation.  In fact, Isabelle/HOL is just another application of Isabelle, so its quantifiers and other binders are defined in user-space by regular mechanisms of the system.

The concepts to look for are "binders", "syntax transformations", "syntax translations" etc. notably in the [Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2014/doc/isar-ref.pdf).  This can be stretched quite far, e.g. see how implicit bindings for [Hoare logic](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/library/HOL/HOL-Isar_Examples/Hoare.html) is done; it is just one small example of many others that have accumulated over the years.

In the Hoare Logic example, the implicit abstraction is introduced via the special syntax constant `_quote`, which is associated with `Syntax_Trans.quote_tr` from Isabelle/Pure -- it is a practically useful concept.  That idea can be pushed even further to allow nesting of quotation/antiquotation (see `$ISABELLE_HOME/src/HOL/ex/Multiquote.thy`), although that did not have practical relevance in applications to the best of my knowledge.

BTW, I would be very surprised if Coq didn't have similar mechanisms for user notation with binders.

Comment: I think "binder" notation is not exactly what I need, because it seems to require an explicit name for the variable that is going to be bound.

Comment: "syntax transformations" on the other hand seem to be exactly what I need. In particular, I think I need something like your Hoare logic's "antiquote" mechanism. I have read the relevant sections in the reference manual, but I am still clueless about how to use these advanced features of Isabelle. If you could point me other resources and examples where I could learn more, I would be grateful!

Comment: In the Hoare logic example, I can see how the antiquote is supposed to apply a term (of type ('a => 'b) ) to an implicit argument (of type 'a ), but it is not clear to me where it finds this implicit argument.

Comment: I've added more hints on Hoare syntax.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a concrete example declaring "binder" notation?

Comment: I have seen the examples in Section 2.3.5 and I know how to declare a constant as a binder as well. But I wonder if it would be possible to declare a binder as part of an abbreviation as well. I would like to be able to write something like this:

Comment: `abbreviation bmbox :: "(i ⇒ σ) ⇒ σ" ("□b") where "(□b v . φ) ≡ (λw. ∀v.  w r v ⟶ φ v)"`

And I would like any occurrence of `v` in `φ` to be bound by the `∀v` when the abbreviation is expanded.

Comment: With so many additional questions and notes, the discussion is better continued on the isabelle-users mailing list.